# running a firefox tar.bz install in my homedir with separate settings from a distro installed firefox

Tags: linux, firefox

Work's mandated a specific version of firefox that's older than I'd like. They're cool with sysadmins and general tech folk running their own stuff (as long as it doesn't trip off the auto "is this installed" script, but I notice that a second install of FF grabs profiles and such from my main install. This isn't quite optimal since I don't particularly want it trampling over my ancient FF install and breaking things.

So... can I just have a *completely* independent copy of firefox that has none of the stuff from my main install (maybe flash at most, but wouldn't be a major thing).

I'm running centos 6.5 if it matters, and I intend to use the tarballed version of FF in my homedir alongside an ESR release. I got root access and such to my system, but I'd rather *not* compile stuff if I can avoid it.

I've tried downloading and running a different version but I can't run two different versions at once, even with -no-remote. I *have* gotten them to run seperately (tho using the same settings and plugins) but not at the same time, by launching the local (tarballed) version with a full path.

So, in short - here's what I've done

- downloaded a tar.bz file with a compiled version of firefox from mozilla
- gotten it running using my default user profile, shared with mozilla from the distro.

Here's what I want to do

- run *both* the distro supplied version of firefox and the tarball at the same time
- have them independent of each other with separate settings, plugins and such.

Comment: You can customize or replace the profile; it's plug-and-play as long as any add-ins in the profile work with the FF version.  To protect the existing profile, temporarily rename the existing mozilla or firefox directory.  Then install the tarball.  You can then do what you need with the profiles.  You can leave the original in reserve, copy from it into the new profile, or have multiple profiles.  The ESR releases tend to be many versions behind the current tarballs, so it would probably be a good idea just to install compatible add-ins on the new installation.

Comment: Yeah, that's *exactly* what I want to do.

Comment: ahh, part of the problem is solved - I need to use the *complete* path for the home directory based firefox

Comment: Installing from a tarball is a bit of a pain in the butt.  You might find an rpm version that's a "1-click" installation.  If the CentOS repo doesn't have one, check the repos for RHEL or Fedora.

Comment: Actually, this is precompiled. Just shuck the archive and run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it worked at work (but not on the test system oddly enough)

There's a few things here

I downloaded and untarred a current release of firefox - which should work standalone. Its under My own files are under `/user_data` so the directory I've untarred firefox is `/user_data/firefox` for me so if you're trying to do this,replace this with your own path. *always* use the full path so you arn't accidentally firing up a preinstalled copy of firefox.

1. run  /user_data/firefox/firefox -no-remote -CreateProfile "profile /user_data/firefox/profile/" to create a new profile inside the firefox folder (which makes this essentially portable).
2. run firefox with /user_data/firefox/firefox -no-remote -P "profile"

This is an independent install of FF so plugins and such won't be moved over from the existing install. You'll need to copy these over as needed. You don't particularly need these tho.

Tested under centos 6.5 (and dosen't quite work in fedora 21 yet)